# Virtual Dedicated Server Question

Tags: java, php, ajax, dedicated-hosting

I have a Virtual Dedicated Server, how can I run an application periodically (ie: every Monday - 19:00). I mean, the application starts automatically at a given time.

Is there any way to do it with Java, Ajax, PHP? (sorry, I'm noob)

Comment: How about using crontab? http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create scheduled tasks in [windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) and [cron jobs](http://unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) in linux/*nix like systems. If you can run programs on the server and want to use java you can use timers to schedule your task - here is a simple [example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your server is linux.
You may be able to do this with webmin. 
You will need to use command line to install webmin and setting up a crontab from command line is really not that hard to do.

Here is a tutorial for crontab. 
http://www.linuxweblog.com/crotab-tutorial

What OS does the server run?